# Import XML to SQL table and format data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Would someone be able to help me I am trying to import an xml file to a sql server table. I can import the required data but having some trouble getting it in the format required.

```
    declare @input XML = '<Sub>
    <Results>
    <Result>
      <ids>
        <id>
          <type>code</type>
          <value>9004a3d2</value>
        </id>
        <id>
          <type>username</type>
          <value>jbloggs001</value>
          <date>20160725</date>
        </id>
        <id>
         <type>EmployeeID</type>
         <value>01234</value>
         <date>20160725</date>
        </id>
     </ids>
    </Result>
</Results>
</Sub>'
   SELECT
     datatype = XCol.value('(type)[1]','varchar(25)'),
    datavalue = XCol.value('(value)[1]','varchar(50)')
   FROM 
      @input.nodes('/Sub/Results/Result/ids/id') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

This gives 3 columns like:

```
datatype       datavalue
--------------------------------
   code        9004a3d2   
   username    jbloggs001
   employeeID  01234
```

Would it be possible to get it to import as?

```
EmployeeID   USername     Code
    ---------------------------------
   01234        jbloggs    0019004a3d2
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use PIVOT -  check out: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in comments that could be done using PIVOT:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
   SELECT
     datatype = XCol.value('(type)[1]','varchar(25)'),
    datavalue = XCol.value('(value)[1]','varchar(50)')
   FROM 
      @input.nodes('/Sub/Results/Result/ids/id') AS XTbl(XCol)
    ) as p
    PIVOT (
        MAX(datavalue) FOR datatype IN (EmployeeID,username,code)
    ) as pvt
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID  username    code
01234       jbloggs001  9004a3d2
```

If input is always with same `type`s:

```
SELECT  XCol.value('(id/value)[3]','varchar(50)') as EmployeeID,
        XCol.value('(id/value)[2]','varchar(50)') as username,
        XCol.value('(id/value)[1]','varchar(50)') as code
FROM @input.nodes('/Sub/Results/Result/ids') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

Comment: The `PIVOT` solution is fine (+1 from my side), but I would not rely on the sort order within the XML. One reason to use XML is the extensibility without breaking existing solutions. It was much more secure to get the nodes with an appropriate XQuery (see my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Below query works for your solution

```
Select [EmployeeID],[Username],[Code]
FROM #TEMP
PIVOT
(
MAX(DATAVALUE) FOR DATATYPE IN (code,username,employeeID)
)A
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is XQuery contains function

```
declare @input XML = '<Sub>
    <Results>
    <Result>
      <ids>
        <id>
          <type>code</type>
          <value>9004a3d2</value>
        </id>
        <id>
          <type>username</type>
          <value>jbloggs001</value>
          <date>20160725</date>
        </id>
        <id>
         <type>EmployeeID</type>
         <value>01234</value>
         <date>20160725</date>
        </id>
     </ids>
    </Result>
</Results>
</Sub>';
   SELECT
    code = XCol.value('(id[contains((./type)[1],"code")]/value)[1]','varchar(50)'),
    username = XCol.value('(id[contains((./type)[1],"username")]/value)[1]','varchar(50)'),
    EmployeeID = XCol.value('(id[contains((./type)[1],"EmployeeID")]/value)[1]','varchar(50)')

   FROM 
      @input.nodes('/Sub/Results/Result/ids') AS XTbl(XCol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very straight and typesafe approach was this:

```
SELECT id.value('(id[type="code"]/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS code
      ,id.value('(id[type="username"]/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS username
      ,id.value('(id[type="EmployeeID"]/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS EmployeeID
FROM @input.nodes('Sub/Results/Result/ids') AS A(id)
```